# Read data from a particular partition in Azure Eventhub using Azure Databricks

Tags: azure-eventhub, producer-consumer

I am trying to read data from azure eventhub using sparkstreaming in Azure Databricks. However I need to write my consumer client in such a way that it reads from a particular partition ID of an eventhub.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.